can no longer add/remove documents for envelopes created through DocuSignApi
For our app, we create envelopes with a document for signing for DocuSign's eSignature app using the DocuSign Api. Everything was fine until Q1/Q2 2024. Now, customers report that they no longer can edit/delete documents as described here
https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=fjx1578456267870.html&_LANG=enus
Envelope is in state created at this point.
When manually uploading a doc, I still can use the feature described above. DocuSign support could not help. Any ideas what might be the problem here?

Is your app using an SDK? which one? which version? can you share the code that does this? what error message do you get?

You need to set ShowEditDocuments = "true" in the DocumentSettings object of the EnvelopeViewSettings that is used to determine the various settings or embedded sending. And yes, this is a new update that was recently launched.
Not sure which lang you're using, I'll assume C#, here is the code you need:
    private static EnvelopeViewRequest PrepareViewRequest(string startingView, string returnUrl)
    {
        EnvelopeViewSettings viewSettings = new EnvelopeViewSettings
        {
            StartingScreen = startingView,
            SendButtonAction = "send",
            ShowBackButton = "false",
            BackButtonAction = "previousPage",
            ShowHeaderActions = "false",
            ShowDiscardAction = "false",
            LockToken = string.Empty,
            RecipientSettings = new EnvelopeViewRecipientSettings
            {
                ShowEditRecipients = "false",
                ShowContactsList = "false",
            },
            DocumentSettings = new EnvelopeViewDocumentSettings
            {
                ShowEditDocuments = "true",
                ShowEditDocumentVisibility = "false",
                ShowEditPages = "false",
            },
            TaggerSettings = new EnvelopeViewTaggerSettings
            {
                PaletteSections = "default",
                PaletteDefault = "custom",
            },
            TemplateSettings = new EnvelopeViewTemplateSettings
            {
                ShowMatchingTemplatesPrompt = "true",
            },
        };

        EnvelopeViewRequest viewRequest = new EnvelopeViewRequest
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
            ViewAccess = "envelope",
            Settings = viewSettings,
        };
        return viewRequest;
    }


Very helpful, thanks!
